# How to access a public Facebook page using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook page of my own. What I would like is to access the posts in that page as a JSON by sending an API call. I do not need to return the content as a embedded web page like we get in the oEmbed. What is the approach to that?

- In the Facebook developer dashboard I have created an application, which means, I have Client Token and App ID incase I need to have ***access_token*** to pass.
- I know the ***Page ID*** of the Facebook page that I need to access

Is that a must Facebook Login integrated to retrieve such public page content?

When I run following command (True values of *page_id*, *app_id* & *client_access* removed here)

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/page_id?access_token=app_id|client_access"
```

I'm getting following error

```
{
   "error":{
      "message":"(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature.. Refer to https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/apps\/review\/login-permissions#manage-pages, https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/apps\/review\/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/apps\/review\/feature#page-public-metadata-accessfor details. ",
      "type":"OAuthException",
      "code":100,
      "fbtrace_id":"Aal5TRTWtw_phIz7-rHzj1L"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/page/feed

This documentation explains how to access the posts.

You will need to navigate to this URL ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
) and add the required permissions for page access. Then choose the Page Token on the right side where it says "User or Page"

You will need page token to access anything page related